# Added UINavigationcontroller to my app and cannot update frame to resolve the issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I added a UINavigationcontroller to my app in Xcode 8 and I am unable to resolve the auto-layout issue(namely, update the frames), see image of my issue below:

[image: Screenshot of app]

I do not have the option to select the update frames button to resolve the auto-layout issue:

[image: Update frames is greyed out]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not about frame of your view. Please select your viewcontroller(root controller for your navigation controller) go to right pane and find options(middle tab) called 'under opaque bars' and 'under top bars' uncheck them. Now content will be rendered under navigation bar.

Comment: thanks, that did it. It's in the attributes inspector, under View Controller section, uncheck both "under top bars" and "under opaque bars". You're a legend.